# Cypress custom commands not recognized by PhpStorm IDE but working in test runner

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I use JavaScript files in our Cypress testing.

In `commands.js` I created a custom command:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('selectDropdown', (dropdown) => {
    cy.get('#' + dropdown).click();
})
```

And in my test file I call it:

```js
cy.selectDropdown('dropdown1');
```

This is working fine when I run the test in test runner. The only issue is, that my IDE (PhpStorm) doesn't recognize that command.

> Unresolved function or method selectDropdown()

How to 'tell' the IDE, that such command exists?

**UPDATE:**

I created an `index.d.ts` file under support folder (however I use only JS files with Cypress and I have `index.js` there already).

In that ts file I put:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
        selectDropdownValue(dropdown, value): Chainable<(string)>;
    }
}
```

Now the `cy.selectDropdownValue` command is recognized in IDE and it seems working fine in test runner, **but there are some problems:**

1. I'll better avoid creating a new TypeScript file, as I have there `index.js` already and I am using only JS files in the project
2. declare namespace - 'namespace' and 'module' are disallowed(no-namespace) - this is a Lint warning, so this needs to be replaced somehow
3. Unused interface Chainable. Not sure if I need to have `Chainable` there as it is unused, and also here `selectDropdownValue(dropdown, value): Chainable<(string)>;`

Can anyone help, how to recognize the custom command by IDE in JavaScript way, not TypeScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I solved it this way as I wrote in my update, just disabled the lint check.

I have checked the built in cypress chainable for some original cypress commands, and there is the same structure so I did it the same way and it works.

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-namespace
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
        selectDropdownValue(dropdown: string, value: string): Chainable<Subject>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting your IDE to get IntelliSense for your custom commands. Check out this document. thanks
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-todomvc#cypress-intellisense

Comment: thank you, so for each custom command i need to write chainable stuff... ehm, then better I live without it, if there is no other way. If I create a custom js function in another file and call it from other file, IDE recognizes it, however it is my custom function. But the custom command is not recognized. I just want to click on that command to take me to the file where it is defined...Strange, but I understand that function is different as command. So thank you for the link

Comment: you are welcome. creating custom function also a good idea but you have to import for all your spec file to consume the methods. @Darksymphony

Comment: Well, I just found out, that the doc shows that I need to declare the namespace in index.d.ts file. But I don't have such file and I am not using typescript with cypress, only js files and in js I can't declare namespace.

Comment: I know it is not so good IDE, but for cypress-intelisence purposes I have Visual studio code with that plugin working nicely, though my primary ide is PHP storm. Also PHP storm needs to be version over 2020 to be able to accommodate it I believe

Comment: I am using PHP Storm 2021 and it doesn't recognize those custom commands. I have also VS Code, although there is no warning, but I am not able to jump to declaration to custom commands even in VSCode by clicking on it. Maybe then I will create that .ts file as I mentioned, but I need help, how to replace 'declare namespace' as I wrote in my updated question.

Comment: this is the one that works on VSCODE, create cypress/support/index.d.ts that includes the namespace declaration

Answer (score 0):

Double check you have this in your `tsconfig.ts`

```js
  "include": ["cypress/**/*.ts"]
```

then your IDE should be able to find the custom cypress commands